# cant able to retrieve data from firestore after ejecting expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

im looking to retrieve data from the firestore.first it worked well when i ejected from expo i cant able to retrieve data from the servers. when i read some documentation they suggested to use

```
      let myApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
myApp.firestore().settings({ experimentsalForceLongPolling: true });
const firestore = getFirestore(myApp);
 but im ettin error myApp.firestore() is not a function.

here is my code:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
const firebaseConfig = {

};
let myApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
myApp.firestore().settings({ experimentsalForceLongPolling: true });
const firestore = getFirestore(myApp);
```

im thinking there is a problem in import can someone help me please

Comment: Hi updated the code as per your error

Answer (score 0):

The settings to enable `experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling` should be enabled through `initializeFirestore` there you will find `settings: FirestoreSettings` argument refer [`FirestoreSettings`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoresettings) which you can set as follows :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeFirestore, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
};

let app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db;

try {
  db = initializeFirestore(app, { experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true }); // <= settings
} catch (e) {
  if (e.code === 'failed-precondition') {
    // Multiple app instances detected
    db = getFirestore(app);
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

And as `initializeFirestore` is equivalent to getFirestore method so no need to reinitialize firestore again as shown in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#initializefirestore):

> Initializes a new instance of Firestore with the provided settings. Can only be called before any other function, including (getFirestore:1). If the custom settings are empty, this function is equivalent to calling (getFirestore:1).

Comment: thanks sir, but im etting this error                                                                         
   FirebaseError: initializeFirestore() has already been called with different options. To avoid this error, call initializeFirestore() with the same options as when it was originally called, or call getFirestore() to return the already initialized instance.

Comment: here is the code 
const firebaseConfig = {,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true,
});